# Нерабочий цикл c++, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c++, циклы

Смысл задачи:

Ввести число вводимых чисел, ввести эти числа и найти их сумму.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0, input, datas;
    cout << "input data" << endl;
    cin >> datas;
    for (int att = 0; att == datas; att++) {
        cin >> input;
        sum = sum + input;
    }
    cout << "answer:\n" << sum;
    cin.get(); cin.get();
}
```

Цикл просто не работает, он пропускается, почему?

Comment: `!att == datas` -> `att != datas`

Comment: Смотрите на свое условие выполнения цикла. Условие ложно - цикл не выполняется. Что вы хотели сказать этим `!att == datas`???

Comment: @AnT это я уже давно исправил, однако цикл все еще не выполняется

Comment: @Igor задачи на указатели еще на разбирал, так что объясни пожалуйста что это и куда это вставлять. Я в принципе понимаю смысл указателей, но не понимаю применения

Comment: @kbx: "Исправил" на что??? У вас теперь написано `att == datas`. Условие все равно ложно, цикл по-прежнему не выполняется.

Comment: @kbx - "куда это вставлять" - главный вопрос современности :). Ваш кусок `!att == datas` заменить на `att != datas`. Это всего лишь сравнение двух чисел, об указателях речи нет.

Comment: @kbx: О каких "указателях" вы ведете речь? Пока что никто не сказал ни слова ни о каких указателях.

Comment: вместо for() пишите  while ( datas--) , чтоб не путали больше ничего

Comment: @AnT -> знак для указателя или альтернатива на *, тут я то и смутился ответом Igor

Comment: @Igor спасибо, опробовал, работает и понял в чем моя ошиька

Comment: @ARHovsepyan тоже опробовал и while (datas--)  оказался удобнее чем тот способ который я хотел применить, спасибо)

Comment: вы обратили внимание на мой коммент, это указывет на ваше стремление знать больше, поэтому всегда рад буду быть вам полезен...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int att = 0; att == datas; att++)
```

Цикл читается как "выполнять, пока att равно datas". Если ввести 0, то один раз он выполнится. Наверное, имеется в виду `att <= datas` ?

Comment: Тогда уж `att < datas`.